# running command-line module methods in node.js

Tags: node.js, command-line, module

I'm trying to run a component.io method from inside a script, though this shouldn't be specific to component.io.

Under normal circumstances, in a terminal, I'd write.
`component install` to install all the dependencies.

I've tried to different methods, but can't seem to get either to work (or show any output).

First I tried including component as a module

```
var componentIO = require('component');
componentIO.install();
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, nothing happens.

When I output `console.log(componentIO)`, it outputs as part of the object `install: [function]`, so I think I'm calling it correctly.

The other way I tried was via child_process

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var componentIO = cp.fork('component');
componentIO.send('install');
```

but again, I don't see any output in the terminal.

Am I taking the wrong tact to run commands from within node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [component-installer](https://github.com/component/installer.js) module to install components.

```
var Installer  = require('component-installer');
var installer = new Installer(__dirname);

installer.on('package', function (pkg) {
  console.log('installing', pkg.name, pkg.version);
});

// arguments: (package name, package version)
installer.installPackage('matthewmueller/io', 'master');

console.log('Packaged installed.');
```

Comment: Though this may be the correct answer with regards to component.io, I am actually trying to get something that works more generally.

Comment: @pedalpete The general way is to pass the full path of `component` to `cp.fork()`. You can run `which component` in the terminal to get the full path.